# Diophantine with factorials

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial, integers

This is a problem I encountered on a competition Discord server, apparently, there is an elementary solution, but I'd honestly be fine with any solution.

Wolfram Alpha solves the problem, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28a%2B1%29%3Db%21%28b%2B2%29)'s the link
(so that people who don't want to see it don't have to).

The problem is to solve (within positive integers) the following:
$$a(a+1)=b!(b+2)$$

I've tried using Bertrand's postulate, bounding, and coming up with some counting arguments, all methods have failed.

Comment: what does  "competition Discord server"  mean? What is the source of the problem?

Comment: I encountered it on Venhances Discord server, I also recently found an Aops link https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2060273p14683264

Comment: So either $b!\mid a$ or $b!\mid a+1$ for a start.

Comment: apparently  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)

Comment: What might help : A positive integer $k$ is of the form $a(a+1)$ if and only if $4k+1$ is a perfect square. So, we get $4b! (b+2)=n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$

Comment: @Jyyonjj FYI, the same equation, in the question title, was just asked about at [Solve $a(a+1)=(b+2)b!$ over positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4150481/602049).

Comment: In general, if Wolfram Alpha solves a diophantine equation , it is not guaranteed that all solutions have been found. This does not mean that Wolfram Alpha could not solve this particular diophantine equation completely.