# Solve $a(a+1)=(b+2)b!$ over positive integers

Tags: number-theory

Since $gcd(a,a+1)=1$ for each prime number $p$: if $v_p(b!)=c,$ we have either $p^c | a$ or $a = 1 \mod p^c$. And we now that $c = \lfloor \frac{b}{p} \rfloor + \ldots$

So it's encouraging that it's solvable but on the other hand,the equation is evaluate to $(2a+1)^2-1 =4b!(b+2)$ which is so similar to Brocard's problem!

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2060273p14683264).

Comment: It's not answered !

Comment: I found with a computer the solutions $(a, b) = (1, 0), \ \
(a, b) = (5, 3)$ for $b = \overline{0,1000000}$

Comment: It can be rewritten as $a(a+1)=b!+(b+1)!$ but I doubt that's useful.

Comment: Again, some more posts on [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1995320p13920909).

Comment: It is commented there that the problem might be open. So where did you get this equation from?

Comment: My source is art of problem solving and the one who asked ''are you sure this problem is not open?'' Is me!

Comment: @Mohammadreza Welcome to Math SE.  Regarding solving the equation in your question title, note this was asked about relatively recently at [Diophantine with factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4130806/602049).